# Solving Running time Big Theta Notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

Consider finding the total running time as function of n in these two loops:

(1)

```
q  <- 1
while q <= n
     p  <- 1
          while p <= q 
           p <- p + 1
     q  <-  2 * q 

(2)
q,s <- 1, 1
while s < n
    for j <- 1 to s        
          k  <- 1
          while k < = j  
                 k  <- 2 * k        
     q  <- q + 1
     s  <- q * q
```

Going off of what I know I believe:
(1) is **theta(n * lg(n))** where n represents time for inner loop, and
lg(n) for the outer loop.
(2) is ****theta(n * lg(n) * sqrt(n))**** where n represents time for the for loop,
sqrt(n) for the outer loop, and lg(n) for the inner while loop.

I am not sure if this is correct. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(1):

This is not the correct way to view this, in fact, the inner `while-loop` does not do "`n` cycles `lg n` times", it does **`q`** cycles whatever this number may be each iteration!

The correct way to analyze this is saying that the inner while-loop runs `q` times, and `q` takes the numbers `1, 2, 4, ... , n` (Yes, the out while-loop runs `Θ(lg n)` times).

Thus the whole running times is:

`1 + 2 + 4 + ... + L` beware that if `n` is not a perfect power of 2, it goes up to the largest power less than `n`. Thus we can say it runs until it hits `n` (`L = Θ(n)`)

Computing this gives us a geometric progression with **`lg(n)`** elements:

`1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n  = Θ(n)`

(2):

Not a final solution, but a hint/kickstart
Your analysis is still wrong by saying the `for-loop` runs `~n` times, this loop simply runs `s` times, and `s` is changing with each and every iteration. On iteration `t` we have `s = t^2`.

The analysis goes as so:
The `for-loop` and its inneer `while-loop` are correlated, `j` runs from `1-s` and the while loop runs `lg(j)` - they are correlated because `j` is changed in each of every iteration of the `for-loop`. But we need to keep in mind that `s` is changing as-well, and so the `for-loop` runs `s ∈ {1, 4, 9, ..., n}`

Comment: So, I've determined through your suggestions that the correlation between s and j is: s lg (s). And the outer loop is sqrt(n), so would it be theta (sqrt(n) (sqrt(n) lg sqrt(n)))  == n lg(n^1/2) == n lg(n).

Comment: @hollyjolly Think again! lets take s=1,4,9 as examples (q=1,2,3) we that the for-loop combined with the while loop are running at: `(lg 1) + (lg1 + lg2 + lg3 + lg4) + (lg1 + lg2 + lg3 + ... + lg9)`. Do you see the pattern? It can be described a formula, using 2 summations, one running over `t` from `1 to sqrt(n)` (signals the `q`) and inside the sum, we have the for-while loops together with the sum from `c=2 to t^2 ` (signals the `s`)

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited by comment while you replied back .

Comment: It is still incorrect, express this as a nested sum formula

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I deleted the comment because it just clicked for me. Sorry for the bothering you more. This stuff is a bit harder for me to grasp so I keep coming back to it.

Comment: @hollyjolly You are not bothering me at all, if something is not clear in my answer, always ping me and I will try my best